# Error files being generated constantly at apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file

I am getting the following kind of errors very fast and I am unable to open up my plesk control panel. My disk space is becoming full at very constant speed. Now I am unable to open up my ftp also. The disk space is rapidly being occupied with error log files.

These are the error messages I am getting. Can anyone please look into this..

```
[root@host353218 ~]# grep -Hr 94.233.235.239 /var/www/vhosts/playtoongames.com/statistics/logs/error_log | grep 09:12
/var/www/vhosts/playtoongames.com/statistics/logs/error_log:[Mon Jun 06 09:12:22 2011] [error] [client 94.233.235.239] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant LOGIN_TITLE - assumed 'LOGIN_TITLE' in /var/www/vhosts/playtoongames.com/httpdocs/lang/en.php on line 4, referer: http://www.playtoongames.com/categories/5/
/var/www/vhosts/playtoongames.com/statistics/logs/error_log:[Mon Jun 06 09:12:22 2011] [error] [client 94.233.235.239]
```

Regards.

Comment: Have you looked at the file '/var/www/vhosts/playtoongames.com/httpdocs/lang/en.php' to correct line 4?

Comment: Hi, i have defined like this...define (LOGIN_TITLE,'Sign In');...this is not only the error..i am getting such kind of so many errors..

Comment: You need to surround `LOGIN_TITLE` with quotes: `define('LOGIN_TITLE', 'Sign in');`

Comment: Even i am using the same code for my other website, but there is nothing problem with it. but for my playtoongames.com its the problem of error log files generation.

Comment: You may have your error_reporting level set to suppress notices for your other sites, but not for this one, hence the notices appearing in your logs.

Comment: you mean i need to suppress the error_reporting level in .htaccess of apache file..

Answer (score 1):

You are using a constant named `LOGIN_TITLE` in "httpdocs/lang/en.php", that is not defined before. It should be either a string (encapsed in quotes `'LOGIN_TITLE'`), or you should define it before.

Update:

[How to define a constant in PHP](http://php.net/define).

```
define('LOGIN_TITLE', 'Sign in');
```

The first argument is the name of the constant as a string, not as a constant itself. The quotes `'` are *required*.

Comment: Hi thank you for your immediate response...i have defined like this..its also working.. define (LOGIN_TITLE,'Sign In');

Comment: Does this mean, the problem is solved, or its this just a comment? Remember to define the constant _before_ you use it.

Comment: No the problem has not solved..between i am getting so many errors like this. what might be the problem. my disk is filling with error log files.check this site.its working fine.. ..http://www.playtoongames.com/

Comment: Please examine this answer again: it is correct. You need to include quotes around the constant identifier, which you said you have not done.

Comment: @George Cummins, i have surrounded with the quotes but still i am getting the same kind of errors.

Comment: Can you post the corrected code, as well as the output you now receive (if it has changed at all)?

Comment: Hi all, its fine now..no errors...thanks for your support...cheers